# Having to enter 'N' twice for it to display relevant information

Tags: java, sorting, compilation

I'm attempting to code something that will sort numbers in ascending or descending order dependent on what the user input. The program is able to sort them in ascending order when the user enters 'Y' however if they enter 'N' to sort in descending order the user has to put 'N' in twice before it displays. I've posted the syntax below so if anyone feels like telling me what's missing/done wrong, please feel free to do so.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SortProgram { 
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nHow many numbers do you want sorted?: ");
        int count = in.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter number #" + (i+1) + ": ");
            array[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.print("\nPress 'Y' to sort numbers in  order, press 'N' to sort numbers in DESCENDING order: ");

        in.nextLine();

        boolean ascending = true;
        boolean descending = false;

        if (in.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0) == 'Y') {
            ascending = true;
        } else if (in.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0) == 'N') {
            descending = true;
            ascending = false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < count - 1; j++) {
                if (ascending) {
                    if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
                        int temp = array[j];
                        array[j] = array[j + 1];
                        array[j + 1] = temp;
                    }
                } else if (!ascending) {
                    if (array[j] < array[j + 1]) {
                        int temp = array[j];
                        array[j] = array[j + 1];
                        array[j + 1] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print("\nThe sorted numbers are: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `descending` even a variable? You don't use it at all.

Comment: Been trying a variety of things to fix, thought I'd try it out. I'm  totally new to Java so I don't know masses. Can you see many errors?

Comment: You should DEFINITELY assign in.nextline() to a variable so you don't keep calling it, and you can just then check the value of the variable. I don't know if this changes anything or not, as I'm not running this right now, but this is a good coding habit

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're calling `in.nextLine()` twice. Every time you call that, the program reads in another thing from the user.

By default, your code runs in ascending order. However, since you get input twice, you need to enter "N" twice (when it "counts" - i.e. the second time, when you actually use the result) for it to work.

Fixing this is simple: just remove the `in.nextLine()` right before you declare `ascending` and `descending`.

By the way, your user-input testing code is a bit more complicated than it needs to be. To set `ascending` correctly, all you need is:

```
ascending = in.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("y");
```

It uses [`equalsIgnoreCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)), which is equivalent to your method of getting the first character, uppercasing it, and comparing it to `'Y'`.

This will replace the if/elseif block before your for loop.

Side note #2: you have a whole lot of duplicate code in that for loop. Since the only thing that varies is the condition in the if block, you can just use a boolean expression instead of an inner if/else statement:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < count - 1; j++) {
            boolean swap = ascending
                    ? array[j] > array[j + 1]
                    : array[j] < array[j + 1];
            if (swap) {
                int temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tried removing, would error after the user inputs which order he wants. Could you perhaps change it for me so I can make sure were on the same page? :)

Comment: What sort of error? To make the code I put in my answer work, you'll need to do two things: remove the call to `in.nextLine()` before you assign `ascending` and `descending`, and replace the entire if/else block right before the for loop with the single line of code from my answer.